# How to merge a remote MS Word document with the active document in a VBA macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

#### Frontend

In the "frontend" I have a macro linked to a button in my command bar within Word. Purpose of this button is to allow users to compare the current document with its previous version.

#### Backend

In the backend I have a Java EE server and Alfresco running with a few servlets. One of these servlets currently returns .doc document when given the document's name. So I just need to call it with the good name containing the version I want and it returns me the document I asked for.

#### Ideal workflow

So the ideal workflow for a user would be the following :

- User opens a MS Word document
- User clicks on a button in the command bar
- User gets a new document containing a merged version of both its current doc and the
  one returned by the server

#### What I want to know

The challenging part for me is the one regarding VB6. I know that I can merge docs with `ActiveDocument.Merge FileName:="path_to_file", MergeTarget:=wdMergeTargetSelected` but

1. How to call a servlet that returns a Word Document that I can use in my VB script?
2. How to interpret the result of this call so I can pas it to the Merge function and create my merged document?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Please stop tagging VBA questions as VB6 questions.

Comment: You should be able to open a Word document directly from the http path to the servlet.  If needed you could then save a copy to the users temp folder for purposes of running the merge.

Comment: Of course a call to the servlet with a web browser opens the document but that's not what I want. End users don't know anything about this servlet, they just use Word to work on their documents. So I need to load theses docs within Word. I tried with GetObjet from Word.Application object but I get an Invalid Syntax error probably caused by the "http://" link.

Comment: I didn't say you should use a web browser. Have you *tried* opening the document in word using the servlet path?

Comment: I tried using the GetObject method from Word.Application object but it did not seem to work. I'm quite new in VBA so I don't know if there are other ways to open document. How can I open the document in word using the servlet path? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a document using `Documents.Open`. See F1-help for help on the different options and paramteters.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenDoc()

    Dim oDoc As Document

    Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:="FILENAME.docx")

    Call oDoc.Merge("PATH-TO-OTHER-DOCUMENT.docx")

    Set oDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```